# Where to define command-line parameter prediction?

Tags: command-line, bash

So when I type:

`grep --recTab`

I get:

`grep --recursive`

## but

(and that's a **big but**) I have defined a few aliases:

```
alias grep-blue='GREP_COLOR='\''1;34'\'' grep --color=always'
alias grep-red='GREP_COLOR='\''1;31'\'' grep --color=always'
alias grep-yellow='GREP_COLOR='\''1;33'\'' grep --color=always'
```

which allow me to do funky stuff like this:

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep-yellow settings | grep-blue power | grep-red true
```

which gives me:
[image: Coloured grep output]
However in my aliases, there is no prediction for the command-line parameters, so typing:

`grep-blue --recTab`

doesn't do anything!

and I had a look at:

[How do I set up bash completion for command arguments?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95211/how-do-i-set-up-bash-completion-for-command-arguments)
[How to create script with auto-complete?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68175/how-to-create-script-with-auto-complete)

but those seem to be a bit outdated and I can't seem to figure it out, because I did find that `/usr/share/bash-completion` contains:

```
# makeinfo and texi2dvi are defined elsewhere.
complete -F _longopt a2ps awk base64 bash bc bison cat colordiff cp csplit \
    cut date df diff dir du enscript env expand fmt fold gperf \
    grep grub head indent irb ld ldd less ln ls m4 md5sum mkdir mkfifo mknod \
```

so I added `grep-blue grep-cyan grep-green grep-grey grep-magenta grep-red grep-white grep-yellow \` next to `grep` but that doesn't seem to help neither!

*What am I missing here?*

Comment: Interesting question, but... was the unicorn *really* necessary? ಠ_ಠ

Comment: It would have been better if it would have been a 14.10 question, but alas, they're off-topic now...  **:-)**

Comment: Look at `/etc/bash_completion`, `/etc/bash_completion.d/`

Comment: I’m still not used to the hammer, but that’s quite clear I think – if you disagree, you know how to reach me.

Comment: Over on U&L: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4219/70524. Also: consider switching to zsh.

Comment: `bash-completion` parses the command’s `--help` and tries to get the list of valid arguments. Does https://github.com/cykerway/complete-alias help?